# Turn based server for iOS/Android App using Google App Engine

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, webserver

I am working on a multiplayer turn based word game for iOS/Android and need to make a server. I have researched and found google app engine. I believe I will use GAE with python but I am open to other suggestions or possible problems.

My plan is to send HTTP requests to the server from the client and have the server respond with JSON. However, I am not sure how to have the server contact a client when the other player had finished their move. Do I check the server every x seconds or is there a better way to do this?

Is there any other information I should know about GAE or turn based servers/games in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

You can check the server every few seconds or so to see if there are any updates. This system is good as it is much easier to do than the second option; however, this will use more battery life, burden your server unnecessarily, and could be delayed.

Your second option would be to use push notifications. iOS and Android have their own push notifications systems, and you are even able to embed information in them (such as a message, if necessary, or a Game ID). This saves battery life, and the server is not burdened by many devices checking for updates every few seconds. Instead, the server notifies each device when an update is available. This system could be more difficult to make, but it is worth it in the end. Use push notifications.

Comment: How would I handle push notifications if client is running the game when the notification is sent?

Comment: iOS (and Android, too) will alert your app when a notification has been received, if your app is open. Once you receive the notification and interpret the information inside, you will act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

iOS/Android each have their own native notification systems (iOS Push Notifications or Google Cloud Messaging).  You should use those.  Or you can use an abstraction like UrbanAirship.